# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: in display the image from sd card

Tags: java, android, numberformatexception

It shows exception Invalid Int "" when pressing Show image button . Could you please tell me how to resolve this exception ?

The below is my code

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    viewHolder.ivGreetings.setImageResource(Integer.valueOf(greetingsList[i]));
}
```

Comment: pass integer to `int i`,its taking `""` string so it cannot convert to integer..thats y NumberFormatException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setImageResource` accepts only the resource identifiers from `drawable` dir for example.

If you want to load an image from file, you need to load it into `Bitmap`, and then use `setImageBitmap();` on the `ImageView`

Comment: @user6829548, provide something more detieled than "*but not works*". It really works, but you ,ight be misusing it.

Comment: Thanks Vlad Matvienko

Answer (score 0):

`greetingsList[i]` is an empty string. You are trying to convert "" to an Integer.

The valueOf(String s) throws NumberFormatException when s cannot be parsed as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Please change by following

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

if(greetingsList != null && greetingsList[i].length != "")
    viewHolder.ivGreetings.setImageResource(Integer.valueOf(greetingsList[i]));
else
    viewHolder.ivGreetings.setImageResource(0);
}
```

Good Luck!